# Undefined control sequence at first line of a document

Tags: latex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig,psfrag}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\refchapter}[1]{Kapitel~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\refsec}[1]{Sektion~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\refeqn}[1]{Gleichung~(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\reffig}[1]{Abbildung~\ref{#1}}

\title{\bf Grundz\"uge der Softwareentwicklung \\
{\small Analyse- und Entwurfsdokument} \vspace{1cm}\\
\centering
\epsfig{file=figures/logo.eps,width=.4\textwidth}
}

\author{Uschi Musterfrau, Detlef Mustermann und Ralf Auchmustermann}
\date{Matr.-Nr. 0815, 0816 und 0817 \\
email: {\tt [uschi|detlef|ralf]@rwth-aachen.de} 
}

\begin{document}

\lstloadlanguages{[ISO]C++}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small, numbers=left, numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, breaklines=true, escapeinside={/*@}{@*/}}


\pagestyle{headings}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\include{vorwort}
\include{analyse}
\include{entwurf}
\include{nutzerdoc}
\include{entwicklerdoc}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{analyse_entwurf}

\appendix

\include{quellcode}


\end{document}
```

this is how my file starts. I didn't even edit it, I received it like this. However, if I want to make a pdf, it gives me the undefined control sequence error at the first line... What is wrong??

Comment: How do you invoke LaTeX?

Comment: what do you mean by "how do you invoke latex"? how I open the file? it's a tex file I just double click and open with TexShop (Mac)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to use TeX instead of LaTeX. TeX won't recognize the \documentclass command. Make sure you use LaTeX.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using a different editor, and now also the other editor works. however, I get a "messed up" pdf file, with blank pages and pagenumbers at the upper left (not intended)..

Answer (score 0):

It might be that one of the tools in your tool chain gets irritated by a [Byte-Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) (BOM), which is a special Unicode character to indicate the endianness used in your file.

Unfortunately, a BOM may have [unwanted side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark#Unwanted_BOMs).

You might try to save the file with another editor which won't add this mark in the beginning, or remove it with a hex editor.

Comment: tried a different editor and it worked. however the pdf file seems to be pretty messed up. Could it be that BOM, or "not" BOM, has had influence on this? thx

Comment: What does "messed up" mean? Do you see any characters? Empty pages? Images? If it is just the layout that is not nice, I assume this is due to different LaTeX packages (speculating).

Comment: Yes empty pages, the footnotes are at the upper left. sometimes the table of contents is not displayed.after every included file, there is blank page.

Comment: @Jayomat: This looks rather like a problem with your document/your LaTeX version. I doubt this is related to the BOM as an incorrect endianness would rather result in no PDF being created at all.

Answer (score 0):

try getting rid of `\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig,psfrag}` if you're using pdflatex.

Comment: alright... maybe you should read some introductory material. `dvips` is one of the back-end drivers used to create .dvi files. You're loading two packages meant for dvi or ps graphics, and you're trying to produce a pdf-- pdflatex doesn't accept any postscript or eps figures (tiff, pdf, jpg, and png for pdflatex).

Comment: you need to provide more information... what tex distribuition are you using? what editor? are you using `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: I use MacTex2009.. it's 1,4 Gb.. TexLive2009 should be the distribution.. I use TexShop as an Editor and LaTeX to make the file..

I got a second editor, TexWorks where I use pdfLaTeX.. 

I get the same results no matter which editor I chose

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps TeXshop doesn't recognize your file as a LaTeX file and runs it with plain TeX or ConTeXt. If you can post your logfile (the beginning) here, we can help you for sure.